# issue in double pointer address addition

Tags: c, pointers, double-pointer

I have got one issue from a open source code in pointers side, which i have tried to replicate in this below small snippet.

```
int main()
{
int **a=0x0;
printf ("a = %d Add = %d\n", a, a+75);
return 1;
}
```

Expectation is to get 75/0x4B but this code gives 300 in 32 bit and 600 in 64 bit machines.

Output:

```
a = 0 Add = 600
```

But the ideology behind to access the added position i.e 75th position in Hash table.

So it should be

```
printf ("a = %d Add = %d\n", a, sizeof (a)+75);
```

But i couldn't able to guess why this 300 or 600 output. could anyone please point out?

I went till a point where there is some left shift internally happening since:

```
75 - 1001011
600 - 1001011000.
```

Solutions are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic resulting in addresses outside of existing object is generally having *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `0x0` is a _null pointer_. That does not mean it uses a representation of all bits zero. You can not cast to address `0` that way (it's a defect in the language since its very beginning).

Answer (score 2):

Pointer arithmetic is always done using the size of what is pointed to. In your case `a` is a pointer to a *pointer to int*, so the unit size is `sizeof(int*)` which in your case seems to be 4 (32 bits). 4 * 75 = 300.

More precisely, `a + 75` adds the byte offset `sizeof(*a) * 75` (note the dereferencing of `a`) to the pointer. What happens is that you are effectively doing `&a[75]`, i.e. you're getting a pointer to the 75:th element.

On a slightly related note, when you print pointers with `printf` you should be using the format `"%p"`, and casting the pointers to `void *`. See e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

As for the different size on 32 and 64 bit systems, it's to be expected. A pointer on a 32-bit system is typically 32 bits, while on a 64-bit system its 64 bits.

Comment: But i have a doubt that here you are talking about multiplication (4*75) but what i have done there is addition. i.e a+75, so as per your explanation it should be sizeof(*a)+75 i.e 4+75 right?

Comment: Thanks in advance @Joachim Pileborg

Comment: One should emphazise that using the wrong format string type specifier invokes undefined behaviour. It is not just a "minor flaw" (the text invokes this impression).

Comment: Sorry for it. if i use %p. please find the result below:

Comment: a = (nil) Add = 0x258

Comment: @Harrish `a + 75` is the same as `&a[75]`. The amount you add is the *index* as though `a` was an array. What the compiler adds as a ***byte offset*** is `sizeof(*a) * 75`. So the final address will be, effectively,  `(int8_t *) a + sizeof(*a) * 75`.

Comment: @Hjey: 0x258 is hexadecimal notation for the decimal value 600, so 0x258 is equal to 600.

Answer (score 1):

The program behaviour is undefined:

1. The format specifier %d is not valid for pointer types: use %p instead.
2. Pointer arithmetic is only valid within and one past the last element for arrays, or one past the address of the scalar for scalars. You can't read a + 75.

Comment: The fact that you cannot read the content of the memory pointed to by `a + 75` doesn't imply that `Pointer arithmetic is only valid for arrays`. Pointer arithmetic is valid. Dereferencing the pointer is another matter.

Comment: @nicola http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p8 .The result of such an operation is undefined.

Comment: @nicola: that is not true. Reading the pointer to one past the end of the array (or scalar) is defined, but reading a pointer beyond that is not. Note that I'm not talking about dereferencing.

Comment: @FitzwilliamBennet-Darcy Given that, the second statement is still not accurate...It is valid for any type of allocated object, not only arrays.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you very much. That last statement needed improvement.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `%p` for printing pointers and `%zu` for a `sizeof` result.

That said, check the type of `a`, it is `int **`, which is the size of a pointer. And, it depends on the platform / compiler.

Pointer arithmetic honors the data type, so the initial pointer is always incremented based on the LHS data type.